# Hadoop 2.8.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 - Resource Manager crashes on NameNode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, ubuntu-16.04, hadoop-yarn, resourcemanager

got the following problem:
I have got a hadoop cluster (2.8.1, java 8) and my Resource Manager keeps breaking after about 30 seconds-1minute or when I try to add any files to hdfs.

I have got 3 VPS (Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS), 1 for Namenode and 2 for Data Nodes. These are mostly for playing around so just have 20gb of space (which i believe should be enough to see some tiny effect of mapreduce working)

contents of my files:

/etc/hosts on each of the servers:

```
135.59.171.41 01-slave 01-slave
188.166.167.150 02-master 02-master
155.59.170.39 03-slave 03-slave
```

hdfs-site.xml on master

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration
    <property>
       <name>dfs.replication</name>
       <value>3</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
        <value>/usr/local/hadoop/store/hdfs/namenode</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml on slaves

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration
    <property>
       <name>dfs.replication</name>
       <value>3</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
        <value>/usr/local/hadoop/store/hdfs/datanode</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

core-site.xml on master and slaves

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
<property> 
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
   <value>hdfs://stegosaurus-server-02-master:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

JAVA HOME is in hadoop-env all 3 servers)

```
# The java implementation to use.
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
```

.bashrc hadoop related all 3 servers)

```
# -- HADOOP ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES START -- #
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib"
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/hadoop/lib/*:.
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/../dev/urandom"
```

mapred-site.xml contents (all 3 servers)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- mapred-site.xml -->
<configuration>
<property>
 <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
<value>yarn</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
<value>02-master:10020</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
<value>02-master:19888</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
<value>-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/../dev/urandom</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml contents (all 3 servers)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
    <value>02-master:8025</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
    <value>02-master:8030</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
    <value>02-master:8051</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

I am using port 51 above because i was trying out all the different ports, including standard ones.

looking at the ports gives the following results

```
02-master:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop$ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN 
sshd     1310     root    3u  IPv4  13858      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
sshd     1310     root    4u  IPv6  13871      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN)
apache2  1452     root    3u  IPv4  15075      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2  1455 www-data    3u  IPv4  15075      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2  1456 www-data    3u  IPv4  15075      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2  1457 www-data    3u  IPv4  15075      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2  1458 www-data    3u  IPv4  15075      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
apache2  1459 www-data    3u  IPv4  15075      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
java     7491   hduser  210u  IPv4 170841      0t0  TCP *:50070 (LISTEN)
java     7491   hduser  226u  IPv4 171053      0t0  TCP 188.166.169.154:9000 
(LISTEN)
java     7718   hduser  220u  IPv4 171925      0t0  TCP *:50090 (LISTEN)
apache2 19108 www-data    3u  IPv4  15075      0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

masters and slaves are filled only on master:
masters

```
02-master
```

slaves

```
01-slave
03-slave
```

Firewall is also off on all 3 servers for now.

What i figured out is that when RM crashes, if i telnet master from master via port that is used by yarn it will be "connection refused"

If i try

```
yarn application -list
```

it will try to connect to resourcemanager address port and die in 10 attempts.

When it loads I can see the web app on ports 8088 and 50070 but then when yarn dies obviously 8088 is not available
I am not sure what else i can add here.
This is quite confusing now because i think i have tried anything now.
Can you help me?

running jps on namenode (please note that resource manager starts and then dies when trying ):

```
7491 NameNode
7718 SecondaryNameNode
12091 Jps
```

the last lines in ResourceManager logs are usually

```
scheduler: class org.apache.hadoop.ipc.DefaultRpcScheduler
2017-10-25 21:01:13,025 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Starting Socket 
Reader #1 for port 8033
2017-10-25 21:01:13,054 INFO 
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.factories.impl.pb.RpcServerFactoryPBImpl: Adding 
protocol 
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.api.ResourceManagerAdministrationProtocolPB to 
the server
2017-10-25 21:01:13,055 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server 
Responder: starting
2017-10-25 21:01:13,055 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: IPC Server 
listener on 8033: starting
```

IP V6 is switched off

Please help.. :(

Comment: How much memory do you have on each host on how much memory/heap have you allocated to each server?

Comment: @tk421 i have got:

**main node:
0 swap, 488m total,146 available**


**data node 1:
488 total, 250 available, 0 swap**

**data node 2:
488 total, 169 available, 0 swap**

I can now see where the problem lies I believe. Is there any suggestion for some minimum amount i would require? maybe 1gig or 2 gig? 

I am not planning to use it for anything big, just playing around - while specs suggest enterprise setups for minimum config

Thanks for you help, i will try to up the memory and see what happens

Comment: I would say 8-10GB total is a good minimum.  In general the heap size of the datanode, node manager and resource manager should be a minimum of 0.6-0.75GB so the total footprint would be 1GB.  The namenode keeps a hashmap of every block in HDFS so you want more memory there like 2-4GB minimum unless you're not planning on generating too much data.  The secondary name node is not necessary if you just want to play around with Hadoop.  An alternative is use one of the pre-packaged VMs (Cloudera or Hortonworks) which already tune their settings to fit in the VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by
@tk421 - the problem was lack of RAM - I have doubled RAM on datanodes and quadrupled ram on NameNode and it started working.

Thanks a lot for your help @tk421 and have a great day !